# How to pivot in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aggregate-functions

Suppose I have the following table. How to pivot three columns prefixed with *part_* per `customer_key` for the top 3 orders?

```
+--------------+----------+---------------+-------------+----------------+
| CUSTOMER_KEY | PART_KEY | PART_QUANTITY | PART_AMOUNT | TOP_ORDER_RANK |
+--------------+----------+---------------+-------------+----------------+
|        10003 |    98909 |            39 |   74,408.10 |              1 |
|        10003 |   157096 |            49 |   56,501.41 |              2 |
|        10003 |   179085 |            42 |   48,891.36 |              3 |
|        10003 |   179075 |            10 |   28,891.36 |              4 |
+--------------+----------+---------------+-------------+----------------+
```

Expected result:

```
+--------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+
| CUSTOMER_KEY | PART_1_KEY | PART_1_QUANTITY | PART_1_AMOUNT | PART_2_KEY | PART_2_QUANTITY | PART_2_AMOUNT | PART_3_KEY | PART_3_QUANTITY | PART_3_AMOUNT |
+--------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+
|        10003 |      98909 |              39 |     74,408.10 |     157096 |              49 |     56,501.41 |     179085 |              42 |     48,891.36 |
+--------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

Example data:

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT '10003' AS CUSTOMER_KEY, '98909' AS PART_KEY, 39 AS PART_QUANTITY, 74408.10 AMOUNT, 1 TOP_ORDER_RANK UNION ALL
SELECT '10003' AS CUSTOMER_KEY, '157096' AS PART_KEY, 49 AS PART_QUANTITY, 56501.41 AMOUNT, 2 TOP_ORDER_RANK UNION ALL
SELECT '10003' AS CUSTOMER_KEY, '179085' AS PART_KEY, 42 AS PART_QUANTITY, 48891.36 AMOUNT, 3 TOP_ORDER_RANK UNION ALL
SELECT '10003' AS CUSTOMER_KEY, '179075' AS PART_KEY, 10 AS PART_QUANTITY, 28891.36 AMOUNT, 4 TOP_ORDER_RANK
    )
```

Comment: what do you mean without aggregqation, you want 3 rows out of 4 in one row, so at least one GROUP BY or pivot you must use and evenb this has an aggregation https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot

Comment: If you really don't have any overlapping records when you are pivoting, then I recommend using an `ANY_VALUE()` function.  This choose any value in the group by result, and since there would only be 1 value in your case, it will perform faster than using a MIN() or MAX() function.  However, as the comment above notes, you must use an aggregate function of some kind.

Comment: Updated the title. I'm not sure pivot function gives the expected result. Let me know if you have a solution. @nbk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot with conditional aggregation. This is standard SQL that does not rely on a vendor-specific implementation such as Snowflake’s `pivot`:

```
select CUSTOMER_KEY,
    max(case when TOP_ORDER_RANK = 1 then PART_KEY      end) PART_KEY_1,
    max(case when TOP_ORDER_RANK = 1 then PART_QUANTITY end) PART_QUANTITY_1,
    max(case when TOP_ORDER_RANK = 1 then PART_AMOUNT   end) PART_AMOUNT_1,
    max(case when TOP_ORDER_RANK = 2 then PART_KEY      end) PART_KEY_2,
    max(case when TOP_ORDER_RANK = 2 then PART_QUANTITY end) PART_QUANTITY_2,
    max(case when TOP_ORDER_RANK = 2 then PART_AMOUNT   end) PART_AMOUNT_2,
    max(case when TOP_ORDER_RANK = 3 then PART_KEY      end) PART_KEY_3,
    max(case when TOP_ORDER_RANK = 3 then PART_QUANTITY end) PART_QUANTITY_3,
    max(case when TOP_ORDER_RANK = 3 then PART_AMOUNT   end) PART_AMOUNT_3
from t1
group by CUSTOMER_KEY
```